# Qual è l'uso di "punto" in questa frase?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Nel racconto *La radura* di Marisa Madieri ho letto:

> "Amanda lo aveva sempre disprezzato a causa della sua malcelata propensione per le fresche coccinelle, che l'età non aveva *punto* scoraggiato."

Non riesco a capire qual è l'uso del vocabolo "punto" in questa frase. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In questa circostanza è sinonimo di "affatto", "per niente". Non si sente troppo spesso nella lingua attuale, tranne che in Toscana, dove è molto usato (addirittura come aggettivo in significato di "nessuno").

Comment: Come disse un tale toscano che conoscevo, dando una spiegazione di geometria, “questo insieme contiene punti punti”.

Comment: @DaG: non sarebbe "punto punti"?

Comment: @Charo: In questo caso no: in Toscana si usa anche come aggettivo, concordato col nome. E vedo ora che il Treccani registra anche questo uso (vedi [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/punto3/), alla fine), con esempi da Collodi («sei veramente sicuro che in quel paese non ci sono punte scuole?»), Carducci, Soffici.

Comment: Mi domando se sia una derivazione dal francese (piuttosto obsoleto) *il n'est point de...*